# Getting Primary key from mysql by given name parameter in Java

Tags: java, jdbc

I am getting exceptions in my java code. I want to get the Id from the given name, Id in this case is a primary key. The Mysql query works when I do query in the workbench:

```
SELECT client_id FROM client where concat(lastname, " ", firstname) = "Hudson Kate";
```

But when I use this query in javacode:

```
public int getClientID(String name) throws SQLException{
        int ID = 0;
        PreparedStatement myprepStmt = null;
        ResultSet myRs = null;

        try {
            myprepStmt = myConn.prepareStatement("SELECT client_id FROM client "
                    + "where concat(lastname, \" \", firstname) =?");

            myprepStmt.setString(1, name);
            myRs = myprepStmt.executeQuery();

            ID = myRs.getInt("client_id"); //this creates a problem

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            close(myprepStmt, myRs);
        }

        return ID;
    }
```

I get this exception :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:937)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:872)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:787)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2460)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2571)
at DBConnection.getClientID(DBConnection.java:135)
at sample.main(sample.java:38)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to use [`ResultSet#next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next-):

```
myRs = myprepStmt.executeQuery();
if (myRS.next()) { //<-- IMPORTANT!
    ID = myRs.getInt("client_id");
}
```

Here's an explanation of how `ResultSet#next` works: [ResultSet.getString(1) throws java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation at current cursor position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10298794/1065197)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I forgot about ResulSet next().