# Set java variable depending on sql return value

Tags: java, sql, if-statement, boolean

I have the following problem:

I need to set a boolean true is an entry in a database exists.

```
        ResultSet rc1 = null;
        int Counterval;
        String url = "jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/dbname"; 
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"",""); 
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        String sqlmd="select count(*) as Counter from tablename where mdsum = '"+mdSum+"' and filename = '"+Filename+"'"; 

        rc1=st.executeQuery(sqlmd);
        Counterval=rc1.getInt("Counter");
        System.out.println("VAL: "+Counterval);
        conn.close();
```

I get the following error message:

```
 [jcc][t4][1090][10899][4.19.26] Illigal operation to read at the current cursor position. ERRORCODE=-4476, SQLSTATE=02501
```

How can I do this? 
I use DB2 if that is of importance

Thanks for your help in advance.

TheVagabond

Comment: Why are you trying executeUpdate when you are just selecting a set of results ? Why are you not trying executeUpdate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you've tried the code, but if you did, what kind of exception are you getting?

You should try `st.executeQuery` instead of `st.executeUpdate` and then just compare if the returning number of `count()` function is bigger than 0

EDIT:
Seeing now your exception in your edited question:

> A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.

```
if (rc1.next()){
   booleanVariable = true;
}
```

This will set the boolean variable in `true` if the variable `resultSet (rc1)` is returning something, it means that in the database there is data according to the query you made. If it returns `false` then it is empty.

I hope it can help you. Greets.

Answer (score 0):

You should call`ResultSet.next()` method first to move the cursor to the first row.

```
boolean check;
String sqlmd="select count(*) as Counter from tablename where mdsum = '"+mdSum+"' and filename = '"+Filename+"'"; 

rc1=st.executeQuery(sqlmd);
rc1.next();
Counterval=rc1.getInt("Counter");
if(Counterval > 0){
 // do something
}else{
 // do something
}
System.out.println("VAL: "+Counterval);
```

According to [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next--) of next method -

> Moves the cursor forward one row from its current position. A
>   ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the
>   first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the
>   second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.

For better understanding read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10298853/3828678).